# Should I send select list data to the view or let it get the data itself?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a create method in my controller and this opens up a view. On the view the user can enter data to populate the model. Some of that data comes from select lists. These select lists are populated from the database.

What I would like to know is should I:

a) Get data for the select lists in the controller, populate a field like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses { get { return GetStatusType(); } }
```

pass Statuses to the model and then do a for () to loop through statuses and create a select list and options HTML

b) Do nothing in the controller and in the view have the following in the model:

```
<select id="Q_StatusID" name="Q.StatusID">@Html.Raw(
SelectHelper.Status(false, @Model.PageMeta.StatusID))</select>
```

Where the SelectHelper is C# code that gets all the select list and options HTML.

c) Some better way:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the first one. some thing like this

a helper method

```
   public List<SelectListItem> getAllSelectList(List<Items> lists)
            {
                List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (Term term in lists)
                {
                    selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = term.yourselectfield, Value = term.your value });

                }
                return selectListItems;
            }
```

on your controller

//assuming you `GetStatusType()` method will return list of objects

```
ViewData.selectlist=getAllSelectList(GetStatusType());
```

on your view, if you are using Razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectlist", null, "Choose")
```

or

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("selectlist", null, "Choose") %>
```

Comment: Do you think there is any performance difference between the methods above?

Comment: I dont think so, but the first one is easy to test and debug.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a static Look-up class & static method for your GetStatusType there.
2. Cache all the status types after first time loading from your database.
3. Call GetAllStatusType from the view to display.

Comment: Can you explain how you would Cache the status types?

Comment: you can do something like

 private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statuses;
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses
        {
            get { return statuses?? (statuses= GetStatusType()); }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I would create a view model, which has a IEnumerable< Statuses > property. Then in your view to display the select element :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PageMeta.StatusID, new SelectList(Model.Statuses, "Id", "Name"), "Some default which has no value")
```

Where Id and Name are set to the appropriate properties in your Statuses model.